# Vimeo API 3.3 Search by tag possible?

Tags: vimeo-api

Is it possible to search by tag with the new Vimeo API? There is no mention of this in the documentation, or at least here: http://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#search

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter to that endpoint includes the title, description and tags. There is not yet a way to find all videos for a specific tag, but we hope to have it soon!

Comment: That's a shame. A platform deal breaker for a public upload competition we want to run. Is the v2 still functional? If so, will it be up until 2015?

Comment: Contact us through vimeo.com/help/contact and ask for the case to be assigned to me. There are a couple of options here, and I can help you more directly via email.

Comment: It has been 6 years since your "but we hope to have it soon!" comment and there still does not seem a method to directly query the Vimeo API for videos with a specific tag

Comment: I no longer work for Vimeo, I would recommend reaching out to their support channels and requesting the feature.